# Does periodic notifications work when device is in sleep

Tags: android, service, notifications

I am working with Android API especially Alarms, IntentService and notifications. I am using `AlarmManager` to schedule a periodic `IntentService` which might or might not fire notifications.

My questions is What happens when the device is in sleep mode?

1. Alarm will not fire and thus `IntentService` will not run at all. I am not sure if this will be the case.Will it make a difference if I make it a WakefulIntentService? I believe wake locks are needed to ensure the service keeps running after the BroadCastReciever returns. However, in this case there is no broadcast reciever.
2. Alarm and IntentService will run, but any notification will not have any impact since the device is sleeping. In this case, do I have to explicitly get a wakelock from PowerManager to fire notification ?

Comment: Yes I am doing notifications too by using a partial wake lock. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens when the device is in sleep mode?

That depends upon your type of alarm and the component your `PendingIntent` is to invoke.

If your alarm type ends in `_WAKEUP`, and you are using a broadcast `PendingIntent`, the device will wake up and remain awake through the call to `onReceive()` of the `BroadcastReceiver`. Once `onReceive()` returns, the device can fall asleep again. This is why `WakefulIntentService` and `WakefulBroadcastRecevier` were created -- to offer tested patterns for how to pass control to an `IntentService` and keep the device awake while the service completes its work.

If your alarm type ends in `_WAKEUP` and you are not using a broadcast `PendingIntent`, as the saying goes, your mileage may vary. You may not get control before the device falls back asleep. This is not a recommended pattern.

If your alarm types does not end in `_WAKEUP`, the device will not wake up due to your alarm.

With respect to the `Notification`, given the nature of the API, one hopes that it is the OS' responsibility to keep the device awake long enough for the ringtone or vibration pattern to play, as we do not know the precise instant when the `Notification` appears, nor do we know whether the ringtone will play (e.g., device is on silent mode).